# Find gmail id based on project id of appspot

Tags: google-app-engine, google-account

I have so many appengine projects running on different google accounts. I have forgotten which google account I have used for one of my appengine projects. Is there a way to find out the google account id based on my project id?

Answer (score 0):

There is not; this would likely be a security concern if it were possible.

The solution would be to iterate over all your accounts and test each account in turn -- like a key -- in the project's lock until you -- hopefully -- find one that works.

You'll want to identify a command that you consider sufficient to determine that you have access, perhaps:

```sh
gcloud projects describe ${PROECT}
```

Then you could iterate across all your authenticated accounts, trying this command:

```sh
for ACCOUNT in $(gcloud auth list --format="value(account)"); do
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --account=${ACCOUNT}
done
```

**UPDATE**
More cute (but in full-disclosure I find `gcloud` filter|formatting challenging cf to jq):

```sh
for ACCOUNT in $(gcloud auth list --format="value(account)"); do
  ROLE=$(\
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
    --flatten="bindings[].members" \
    --filter="bindings.members=user:${ACCOUNT}" \
    --format="value(bindings.role)")
  printf "%s\t%s\n" ${ACCOUNT} ${ROLE}
done
```